# webcomponents.org creating a demo for your element

Tags: github, polymer-2.x

quick question. When publishing an element to webcomponents.org, many elements have a nice demo, which you can open on the side and preview the element.

I created a demo for my element in demo/index.html but I can't figure out how to link this page properly for webcomponents.org to recognize.

I tried replicating the entire structure of the polymer/paper-button element, but it didn't work.

I'm using the Polymer 2.0 preview and the iron-demo-helpers to format the example.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `bower.json` you can provide multiple demos via

```
"demos": {
    "Demo": "demo/index.html"
},
```

for the inline demo you can add something like this to your `README.md`

````
## Demo
<!---
```
<custom-element-demo>
  <template>
    <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="grain-read-more.html">
    <next-code-block></next-code-block>
  </template>
</custom-element-demo>
```
-->
```html
<grain-read-more>
  <h3>Read More</h3>
  <div slot="more">
    The Content is only visible if grain-read-more is opened
  </div>
</grain-read-more>
```
````

Comment: I've just commited a new change to my element to test out the bower tip. I'll accept your answer, if it works

Comment: glad I could help :)